# Migrating Xcode 10 shows asset catalog error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Previously I was working in Xcode 9.4. After migrating to Xcode 10 then shows core data error. But I am not using core data in my project. Here I have shared my log[image]

Comment: check any xcdata.model created in your project ?

Comment: There is no xcdata data model

Comment: Just to make sure: did you try the obvious (clean project, remove DerivedData)?

Comment: yah, but could not resolve